# Android app not working in kitkat version but works in sandwich?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I have a simple networking application which acts as a wifi server for html pages but suddenly when i updated my tab to kitkat from jellybean its not working. and it works fine with my mobile which is sandwich ?

is there any update in kitkat version for this. Please help me i want my app to run on all versions from 2.3

Comment: Do you get any error?? If yes, please post your logcat error.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In main feast file just check what is your minsdk and targetsdk define :)

Comment: minimum is 15 and target is 17 ? anything to do with this.

Comment: yes min define according to 2.3 and why u define target just delete that line and run :)

Comment: if u write target 19 then it will be fine on kitkat but when ever 20 will come then same prob will arrive again so just delete target sdk

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot. finally its running again. :)

Comment: i got a problem mate, when i mention target sdk its not working, but when i say do not mention it it works fine but the app is zoomed, so what do i do please help

Answer (score 1):

The targetsdk in manifest should be 19 for kitkat the version code is 19. Hope it helps you.

Comment: if u write target 19 then it will be fine on kitkat but when ever 20 will come then same prob will arrive again so just delete target sdk

Comment: deleting target sdk making the app looks zoomed in tab, but it works mate the problem is with sdk version thank you.